# What does いけると mean?

Tags: verbs, reading-comprehension

> 泊まってもいいですか?　まだ離れたくなくて。。

"It's ok if I stay over? I don't want to be separated yet..."
To which the other character thinks

> (そう言えばいけると思ってるな　いいけど。。。)

I don't understand how いける is being used here. I know いける is use for "going well" but I don't see how it related here

Comment: そう言えばいける is an idea that is quoted with と, and which is therefore what the character 思ってる. There isn't any いけると idiom; the pattern is Xと思う (with whatever conjugation of that verb).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does どうかと思う mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70250/what-does-%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b%e3%81%a8%e6%80%9d%e3%81%86-mean)

Answer (score 1):

This いける (potential form of いく) means "will work out" or "will do", referring to whatever the first speaker is trying to achieve in this situation.

> そう言えばいけると思ってるな。いいけど...
>
> She thinks putting it like that will work. Well, fine...

From the provided context alone, I cannot tell whether her goal is simply to stay over, or if there's some other purpose beyond just staying.